# Emberjs Page Template Model

Tags: ember.js

I have returned data from server that contains page data that I am trying to use in a model. You can see the json here https://gist.github.com/bungdaddy/11152304. If you take a look at collection.template.data this is the data that I need in my model, which I have put together like so.

```
var PageTemplate = Ember.Object.extend();

PageTemplate.reopenClass({
    all: function(){
        return $.getJSON("http://myurl.com").then(function(response){
            var pageTemplate = [];

            var template = response.collection.template.data;

            template.forEach(function(data){
                pageTemplate.push(PageTemplate.create(data));
            });

            return pageTemplate;
        });
    }
});

export default PageTemplate;
```

This returns json, but my issue is, how in the template.hbs would I target an inner array like collection.template.data[10].acceptableValues? I could build a model just for this array, but I would like to have a PageTemplate with one call to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at a way to display

```
collection.template.data[10].acceptableValues
```

in your template, then all you need to do is set up a computed property on your model/controller that looks something like:

```
prop: function() {
  return this.get('collection.template.data').map(function(item) { 
               return item;});
}.property('collection.template.data')
```

Then in your handlebars you could just use

```
 {{#each prop}} 
 //blah
 {{each}}
```

Comment: thanks Hrishi, and if I have multiple computed properties in reopenClass() how do I send that to a handlebar template

Comment: @Bungdaddy you don't "send" them, you just reference them in your Handlebars template as Hrishi has in the last step of his answer.  Ember handles the binding and reference management.  If you have multiple computed properties, you just references each of them as you need to.

Comment: thanks @MattBaker, I guess my problem is in my Route. `export default Ember.Route.extend({model: function(){
return PageTemplate.all();}});`

Comment: @Bungdaddy ah yes.  If you don't override `setupController` in your router it will automatically assign your model's resolved Promise (`Router.model` blocks until the Promise resolves) to the `model` property on the controller.  Unless it's an ArrayController, then it's `content`, or an `ObjectController`, then it's `target`.  So you would want to reach into the appropriate `model` property to get at your objects, depending on the type of Controller you have.